# Swift - UIAlert with image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uialertcontroller

I have this code:

```
var zdjecieGlowne: UIImage? = nil
let alert = UIAlertController(title:"MyTitle", message: "My Message Box ", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "MyTitle", style: .default, handler: nil)
//saveAction.setValue(UIImage(named: "logo")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
saveAction.setValue(zdjecieGlowne, forKey: "image")
dump(zdjecieGlowne)
alert.addAction(saveAction)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option 1", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
    //alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("1 pressed")
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option 2", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
    //alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("2 pressed")
}))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Option 3", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { alertAction in
    //alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("3 pressed")
}))

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

As a result, I receive Alert with a blue background instead of a picture. Why is it like that?

Comment: bz your image is nil `zdjecieGlowne: UIImage? = nil` , pass your image

Comment: I wouldn't trick `UIAlertController`, that could lead to unwanted results in future versions and potentially a reject from Apple: "The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified."

Comment: bz your image is nil zdjecieGlowne: UIImage? = nil , pass your image - I have image in this variable

Comment: I use this code: https://stay2swift.blogspot.com/2017/09/how-to-adding-image-to-uialertcontroller.html. ZM modified only the image into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code in swift

```
saveAction.setValue(UIImage(named: "name.png").withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
```

or try this

```
saveAction.setValue(zdjecieGlowne.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
```

Comment: I can't write "name.png" because I have only image in var zdjecieGlowne: UIImage? = nil.    self.zdjecieGlowne = obrazek (I have data from internet). When I'm try use this code in normal UImageView - them it's working: @IBOutlet weak var logoRankingu: UIImageView!  logoRankingu.image = obrazek

Comment: extra :) https://ibb.co/k2d5px is it possible to display this image proportionally to the width? At the moment, the picture was wide with me? At the moment it is too high :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
[saveAction setValue:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name.jpg"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forKey:@"image"];
```

In Swift:

```
saveAction.setValue(UIImage(named: "image-name.jpg").withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")
```

Comment: can you give me this in Swift?

Comment: Follow this http://www.stringcode.co.uk/alertviewcontroller. It could help.

Answer (score -1):

You can add your image like the below code

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40))
imageView.image = yourImage
alert.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40))
        imageView.image = zdjecieGlowne
        alert.view.addSubview(imageView) - 'CGRectMake' is unavailable in Swift

Comment: It shows the image above all text in the alert.